# Events: Get Event Observer from Observed

Tags: c#, events

I'm not sure how to get a collection of the observers of an event from the observed class, when using events and delegates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

In this example an instance of EventListener is subscribed to an instance of ListWithChangedEvent. Using the vanilla observer pattern it would be easy to get a collection objects that are listening to ListWithChangedEvent (as it has to maintain a collection of observers anyway). However, using events, its a bit less clear how to produce this collection within ListWithChanged of the observer objects.

Is it something like:

```
Changed.GetInvocationList().Select(item => item.Target).OfType<EventListener>().ToList();
```

Seems doubtful, it seems a bit complex.

Edit: This compiles and gives me my answer. I'm just a bit wary that its a bad way to do it.

Comment: Did it compile? Did it work? Can you break it?

Comment: Are you trying to do this *within* the object that is responsible for the event? What are you trying to achieve with this? What would you want to happen with static methods? You should also bear in mind that the code doing the subscription may not be the code containing the method which handles the event...

Comment: @Gusdor Yes. It did compile, sorry, i thought it wouldn't. I'm still suspicious of it though, I'm suprised its that much hassle to simply get the list of listening class instances.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, thank you, I had not considered these things. I'm going to rethink why I want this collection. I would still like to know if I've answer my own question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just about there, you just have to remember that you can't use GetInvocationList() on delegates marked with `event` from outside the declaring class, so you need to either declare a backing field or make the call from within the class.

```
class EventListener
{
    public EventPublisher publisher = new EventPublisher();

    public EventListener()
    {
        publisher.Event += HandleEvent;
    }

    void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

class EventPublisher
{
    public event EventHandler Event;

    public List<EventListener> GetListeners()
    {
        return Event.GetInvocationList().Select(i => i.Target).OfType<EventListener>().ToList();
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you're dealing with a 3rd party class, so you can't use a backing field or call GetInvocationList() within the class, then you can use reflection:

```
var fieldInfo = typeof(EventPublisher).GetField("Event", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var eventHandler = (EventHandler)fieldInfo.GetValue(listener.publisher);
var listeners = eventHandler.GetInvocationList().Select(i => i.Target).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. But do you know how the explicit way you've declared the Event differs from the standard implementation?

Comment: You *can* get at the delegate itself within the class that declares a field-like event. (I've just double-checked to be sure.) Also note that your event implementation isn't thread-safe, unlike the implementation for field-like events.